# How include jQuery-File-Upload in my model?

Tags: python, django

friends. I am try using [jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload) in my project. Project including two apps:
Orders, Fileupload. Orders have a model:

```
from fileupload.models import Picture  

class Order(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name=u'Название')
born = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="День создания", default=timezone.now)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name=u'Пользователь')
email = models.EmailField(verbose_name=u'Почта')
name = models.CharField(max_length='200', verbose_name='Имя представителя')
phone = models.CharField(max_length='12', verbose_name=u'Телефон')
city = models.CharField(max_length='100', verbose_name=u'Город')
body = models.TextField(verbose_name=u'Описание проекта')
files = models.ForeignKey(Picture, default='', verbose_name=u'Файлы проекта')
```

I want to insert jQuery-File-Upload in my model. How to do it?

Comment: IMO [this blog post](http://garmoncheg.blogspot.kr/2011/07/django-creating-multi-upload-form.html) would be more useful to you...

Comment: I want to connect it to my model through foreignkey.